# Integrate a product of rect functions

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate this product of two rect functions:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \prod \left(\frac{t - \tau}{T_0} \right) \prod \left(\frac{t}{T_0} \right) \mathrm{d}t$$

I'm having trouble to understand how to operate if I have $\tau$ as an independent variable. I know that I should treat it as if it was a constant, but, depending on its value, this integral can have different integration limits. Can I have a hint of how should I start to analyze this?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you mean $dt$ instead of $dx$?

Comment: @AlexR. Yes, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: This should be straightforward. The rectangle function is zero outside a certain interval. It should be clear that if $\tau$ is either too big or too small, both the rectangle functions will have disjoint support (where they are nonzero) and hence the integral is 0. So just work out the interval they have a common nonzero value on.